# ¿Cómo actualizar un datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

Estoy trabajando con vb.net 2015 tengo un winform1 con un **datagridview** que manda a llamar a un winform2 cuando guardo el dato escrito en **winform2** deseo que actualize el datagridview del winform1 atravéz de una función que recibe como parámetro un datagridview el inconveniente es que cuando reviso paso a paso el observo que todo corre bien pero no me actualiza el **datagridview.**

Esta es la función del winform2, le paso el datagridview del winform1

`claseDepartamento.mostrarDatos(frmDepartamento.dgvDatos)`

Así actualizo el datagridview

```
Sub mostrarDatos(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    ConexionClass.consulta("SELECT idDepartamento AS ID, nombre AS DEPARTAMENTO FROM dbo.catDepartamentos order by ID", "catDepartamentos")
    dgv.DataSource = ConexionClass.ds.Tables("catDepartamentos")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

aqui tienes una funcion que podrias mandar a llamar luego de un
update o insert para refrescar el datagridview

```
Private Sub refreshDatagrid()
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=reerp;User ID=root;Password=root;")
    Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users", con)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()
    con.Open()
    DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql
    DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "Users")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Users"
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

suerte espero te sirva !!

Comment: Gracias por el aporte tomé tú código y lo metí a una clase en la cual al momento de mandarla a llamar no realiza nada el código quedó de la siguiente manera

Comment: metí en una clase tú código y al ejecutarla no genera nada es como si no reconociera el datagridview que le estoy indicando

Comment: Public Sub refreshDatagrid()
        
        Dim sql As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT idDepartamento AS ID, nombre AS DEPARTAMENTO FROM dbo.catDepartamentos order by ID", con)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim DataAdapter1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
        con.Open()
        DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql
        DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "DEPARTAMENTO")
        frmDepartamento.dgvDatos.DataSource = ds
        frmDepartamento.dgvDatos.DataMember = "DEPARTAMENTO"

Comment: espero te sirva:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/w8wAp50N

Comment: revisa tambien la conexion dado que en el codigo quete adjunto (pastebin) mando como parametro cnString lo cual es parametros de conexion a tu database